# Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", desc) behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome, ecmascript-5

If I define an object and set its configurable property to false, but leave all other props alone, and later attempt to set that object's writable prop to false, then back to true, a TypeError is thrown.

Here's a breakdown of how I'm doing this, although I have attempted this by altering only one object data descriptor in dot notation, and also by altering all data descriptors of the object in object literal, and neither form has worked.

```
// simple object, and the data descriptor
var o = {name : "tom"},
    dataDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "name");

noConfig();
alert(dataDesc.writable);  // alerts true

readOnly();
alert (dataDesc.writable); // alerts false

writable();
alert (dataDesc.writable); // error is thrown within writable() - alerts true

// early in the script, altering only configurable property
function noConfig(){
  dataDesc.configurable = false;
}

// later in the script, altering only writable property
function readOnly(){

  dataDesc.writable = false; // configurable = false; writable = false;
  Object.defineProperty(o, "name", dataDesc); // works finely
}

function writable(){
    try{
      dataDesc.writable = true; // configurable = false; writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(o, "name", dataDesc); // throws TypeError
    }catch(e){
      alert(e); // alerts: "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: defineProperty"
    }
}
```

I could find nothing to help in the spec, but the MDC article for defineProperty states that, even after an object property is rendered unconfigurable, the writable data descriptor can still be modified. All others cannot, but writable can.

So, is this something in Chrome, or am I doing this wrong?

/* UPDATE */

This has been resolved - just read the spec 8.12.9 section 10.a.i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't coming from `dataDesc.writable = true;`, it's coming from `Object.defineProperty(o, "name", dataDesc);`...which is correct, since `{name : "tom"}` *does* already have a `name` property defined.

This is the correct behavior, you *are* able to change `writable` and *not* able to redefine the `name` property.

I think the confusion comes from the behavior, you don't need to call `.defineProperty()` for `.writable` to take effect, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yTaL6/1/).

**Note:** I commented out `.configurable = false` in the above example, which would lock the property attributes and not allow you to change `writable` further, leaving it stuck in `false` in your original code.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but as was pointed out to me on the V8 issues forum, I only needed to read the right parts of the spec. :P Thanks for helping!

Comment: Nick, you must have read my mind, I literally just figured that out a second ago. I was trying to be all propert by calling defineProperty every time, when I didn't actually need to. :P Thanks again, buddy!

Comment: Yeah, commenting out configurable works, for sure, but then the object is allowed to be deleted or renamed... It would be ideal if I could make it non-configurable and readOnly, but the spec says that if it's non-configurable, and you attempt to change the writable prop from false to true, it will throw an error. And I can't think of any workaround.

Comment: @Tom - I'm not following 100%, you want to lock the object but not have `writable` messed with? Something like `Object.seal()`?

Comment: More like Object.freeze ... Early in the script, just after object creation, I set configurable to false. I allow user's to specify callbacks, so just before callback I wanna set writable to false, then just after set back to true. Keeping it safe for duration of user's callback.

Comment: Is this true for *all* properties on the object you're dealing with, e.g. is passing them their own copy an option?

Comment: Sure, but for extra air tight security I wanted to implement some of the ES5 Object props. I give the user a get fn(){} function to access stuff, but the objects used internally are in the same scope as the callback is defined, and I don't want them to accidentally (or otherwise) screw something up. I guess I'm gonna have to choose between non-configurable or non-writable.

Comment: @Tom - I'd say `configurable: false` myself, that limits them to *intentionally* screwing with it...otherwise pass a copy to eliminate all doubt - though it may be more painful on your side to do so.

Comment: configurable, you think? Hmm. I think I agree. Haha, yes that would be painful. Well, it's a jQuery plugin, and from the HTML page, the user has no direct access to anything going in in the plugin, so it ain't all so bad. :) Thanks again for your help dude! :D